# Do the SQLite JSON functions preserve object property order?

Tags: json, sqlite

Newer JavaScript engines and versions of the EcmaScript standard preserve the order of properties within objects. For instance, iterating over `{ foo: 42, bar: 10, baz: 20 }` is guaranteed to yield first `foo`, then `bar`, then `baz`.

SQLite offers a number of [JSON functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) for reading, modifying, and creating JSON strings.

**Are the SQLite JSON functions guaranteed to preserve property order?** In particular, if I use `json_replace`, will all properties of all JSON objects in the JSON string retain their order?